# How to make a command to insert a subtree in forest?

Tags: macros, forest, trees

I need to make several syntax trees using forest, and there are some structures that show up over and over again in multiple trees. How can I achieve this? So far attempts I've made with `\newcommand` haven't worked. As a basic example, I'd expect to be able to enter something like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\asdf}[1]{a [#1] [c]}

...

\begin{forest}
[x
    [y]
    [\asdf{b}]
]
\end{forest}
```

and produce this tree:

[image: A tree with the root node x, the nodes y and a as children of x, and then the nodes b and c as children of a]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: here's a more complete example of what I'm trying to do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\renewcommand{\ln}{\textit{n}}
\newcommand{\uX}[1]{\sout{u#1}}
\newcommand{\mvmt}[1]{\textlangle#1\textrangle}
\newcommand{\basen}[1]{
\ln
[\ln
    [#1{[N]}]
    [\ln {[\uX{N*}]}]
]
[\mvmt{#1[N]}]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[D
    [the{[D,\uX{\ln}]}]
    [\basen{dog}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

with this as the intended result:

[image]

sorry for not being clearer to begin with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a `forest` environment, Forest's parser is responsible for reading in the content and expanding things etc. This means that ordinary parsing is suspended and macros don't get expanded as you might expect.

Forest provides a mechanism (actually several mechanisms) for temporarily switching its specialist parser off and enabling ordinary expansion. In your example, the easiest way to manage it is to simply set an `action character` and precede the macro `\asdf` with that character. The character can be anything you like which won't interfere with other things. (For example, it obviously wouldn't work to use `[` or `]` or something.) I usually use `@`.

The only potential pitfall is to try defining the character after the `forest` environment has started. It's too late then, because Forest's parser is already running the show. Instead, use `\bracketset{}` outside the Forest environment.

If this sounds involved, it isn't. In practice, all you need is this:

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand{\asdf}[1]{a [#1] [c]}

\begin{document}

\bracketset{action character=@}
\begin{forest}
  [x
    [y]
    [@\asdf{b}]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: tree with expanded macro]

## EDIT

For the more complex case in the edited question, exactly the same approach can be used.

```
\begin{forest}
  [D
    [the{[D,\uX{\lynx}]}]% avoid changing \ln
    [@\basen{dog}]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

gives

[image: output for more complex case with expanded macro]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\asdf}[1]{a [#1] [c]}
\newcommand{\lynx}{\textit{n}}
\newcommand{\uX}[1]{\sout{u#1}}
\newcommand{\mvmt}[1]{\textlangle#1\textrangle}
\newcommand{\basen}[1]{
  \lynx
  [\lynx
    [#1{[N]}]
    [\ln {[\uX{N*}]}]
  ]
  [\mvmt{#1[N]}]
}

\begin{document}

\bracketset{action character=@}
\begin{forest}
  [x
    [y]
    [@\asdf{b}]
  ]
\end{forest}


\begin{forest}
  [D
    [the{[D,\uX{\lynx}]}]
    [@\basen{dog}]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't know that. +1

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `prooftrees` depends on it (AND the `environ` trick).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Will `\lynx` do?

Comment: ;-) how could a cat object that? (Of course, there is a chance that one day the Ti*k*Zling family will have a lynx .... ;-)